# Automapper Custom Resolve logic using Projection

Tags: entity-framework-6, projection, automapper-10

I have an EF object Account that has 4 xrefs off for different portfolio types.  For simplicity, I will call these types A, B, C, and D.

```
public class Account
{
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public PortfolioTypeAXref { get; set; }
    public PortfolioTypeBXref { get; set; }
    public PortfolioTypeCXref { get; set; }
    public PortfolioTypeDXref { get; set; }
}
```

My destination object is a flattened object.

```
public class AccountDto
{
    public long AccountId { get; set; }

    public PortfolioType PortfolioType { get; set; }  //this is an enum with values A, B, C, D, Unknown
    public long? PortfolioId { get; set; }
}
```

Each Xref object looks something like this

```
public class PortfolioTypeAXref
{
    public long XrefId { get; set; }
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public long? PortfolioTypeAId { get; set; }
    public long? HypotheticalPortfolioTypeAId { get; set; }
}
```

I am using linq to Ef projection to translate my object.  I've also written a custom Value resolver, but when using `MapFrom` I noticed it says it is not for projections.

The logic for the resolver essentially checks which (if any) of the xrefs have a portfolio id assigned, and if they do, return an enum with the appropriate value.

```
profile.CreateMap<Account, AccountDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PortfolioType, opt => opt.MapFrom<PortfolioTypeResolver>())
            .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

However, this causes an error, likely because using `MapFrom` with a custom resolver isn't meant to work with projections.  I'm not married to the idea of using a custom resolver - it could just be a function call, but how do I set the destination property based on custom logic that uses the value of the source object?

Comment: Show us the code without AM, just write a LINQ query that works and does what you want.

Comment: Manually mapping is not an option I'd like to explore.  This object has a very large and complicated graph.

Comment: That's not relevant. It's just a test. Then we'll see how AM fits in.